# Get image width and height in pixels

Tags: eclipse, image, height, width, pixel

so i have looked at a couple other questions like this and from what i saw none of the answers seemed to answer my question. I created a program that creates ASCII art, which is basically a picture of text instead of colors. the way i have the program set up at the moment you have to manually set the Width and Height of the pixels. If the width and height of the pixels is too large it simply wont work. so basically what i want to do is have a function to automatically set the width and height to the size of the picture. http://www.mediafire.com/?3nb8jfb8bhj8d is the link to the program now. I looked into pixel grabber but the constructor methods all needed a range of pixels. I also have another folder for the classes, http://www.mediafire.com/?2u7qt21xhbwtp

---

on another note this program is incredibly inefficient, i know that it is inefficient in the grayscaleValue() method, but i dont know if there is any better way to do this. Any suggestions on this program would be awesome too. Thanks in advance! (this program was all done on eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you read the image into your BufferedImage, you can call getWidth() and getHeight() on it to get this information dynamically. See the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). Also, Use a constructor for GetPixelColor to create the BufferedImage once and for all. This will avoid reading the entire file from disk for each channel of each pixel.

For further code clean up, change series of `if` statements to a switch construct, or an index into an array, whichever is more natural. See [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for an explanation of the switch construct.

One last comment: anything inside a class that logically represents the state of an object should be declared non static. If, say, you wanted to render two images side by side, you would need to create to instances if GetPixelColor, and each one should have its own height and width attributes. Since they're currently declared static, each instance would be sharing the same data, which is clearly not desireable behavior.

Comment: you know i really should have looked there too... thanks a lot though! any suggestions on how to make the program more efficent?

Comment: yes it is.. this is the first program i have ever used images in so i am new the the BufferedImage class would you mind posting some adapted code for me?

Comment: Alright! thanks a lot! that is the biggest problem i have been having.. i was looking at other programs that were on the web and was amazed at how fast the image would load

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add the getHeight and getWidth methods to the interface. [Here's](http://www.mediafire.com/?1a2jez82zidum2q) the corrected version.

Comment: unfortunately there are errors, aside from bracket errors and not being able to convert from buffered string to string, and semi colons, in the ASCIIartFrame there are errors because the The constructor GetPixelColor() is undefined... there are other errors after this but i think this is because color is never made.. any ideas why this is happening now?

Comment: oh also there is no method setFile, but it is called upon

Comment: did you want me to change the the constructor method so that when i construct it the ASCIIartFrame it also gives it the string for the file name?

Comment: No need to panic i got all of the errors out, a lot of things needed to be changed to static and i needed to make another constructor method for the setRes() method i ran it and it runs infinatly faster, im still going to change everything so the set height and set width and everything are removed and it works better... thanks a lot! when i finnish the code i will post the new version so you can look at it.

Comment: one more thing i understand what you did in the getCharValue() method but i dont understand what you did in the fontArt() method with the switch and case things.. care to explain?

Comment: so switch is just something that is needed to use that method of coding? what is the advantage to doing it that way? is it just more efficent?

Comment: alright thanks a lot ill keep you in mind when i run across a problem thanks again for all the help!

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?3nb8jfb8bhj8d
^ program

http://www.mediafire.com/?2u7qt21xhbwtp
^ code

Comment: Hi guys, please don't use the commenting system as a chat room. It is for leaving a few comments and prods for more information to a question or answer, not for long debates. The reason behind this is that most of the time (and this is one of them), a lot if not all the comments belong as edits to the question/answer to make that more complete. If I have to read a half-page answer + 3 pages of comments, the focus on the comments is too big. Please edit in pertinent details into the answer instead. If you really need to chat, find/create a chat-room on the Chat site, link at the top of the page

Comment: @Lasse Sorry about that, I guess I'm not entirely used to the format here yet. I've consolidated the important points that came up in the discussion and deleted all of my comments. I'll keep this in mind for the future. Thanks!